# mysql order by dayname

Tags: php, mysql

how do I order in mysql by day name ie: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday so on

```
SELECT 
    DAYNAME(dl.bookingDate) AS dayName, COUNT(dg.idDiary) AS totalBooked
FROM
    diary_list dl, diary_group dg
WHERE
    dl.idDiary = dg.idDiary AND dg.idService != 0 AND dl.status = 3
GROUP BY 
    dayName
ORDER BY 
    dayName ???
```

Comment: should be  ORDER BY  DAYNAME(dl.bookingDate)

Comment: No, DAYNAME returns a string value, and f.e. Saturday will be sorted before Sunday. Use DAYOFWEEK instead, that returns 1 for Su, 2 for Mo, etc.

Comment: Have a look at the WEEKDAY() from the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the function `DAYOFWEEK` to your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`:

```
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(dl.bookingDate)
ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(dl.bookingDate)
```

You may also want to look into using explicit ANSI standard `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT 
    DAYNAME(dl.bookingDate) AS dayName, COUNT(dg.idDiary) AS totalBooked
FROM
    diary_list dl
JOIN diary_group dg
    ON dl.idDiary = dg.idDiary
WHERE
    dg.idService != 0 AND dl.status = 3
GROUP BY 
    DAYOFWEEK(dl.bookingDate)
ORDER BY 
    DAYOFWEEK(dl.bookingDate)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can to make own Order criteria :

```
ORDER BY FIELD(DAY , '3', '4', '5', '6', '7','1', '2')
```

In your case :

```
ORDER BY FIELD(DAY , '7','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')
```

Read this [article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/) for more information